# Google Sheets - Performing a Wildcard Search on a List of Keywords

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Logic:
I have two columns that contain descriptive strings in one sheet.
I have another sheet that contains a list with Keywords and corresponding categories associated with them. I want the category to appear if the Keyword is Contained within the string of either descriptive column.

Scenario Example:
I am creating an advanced custom budget.
I have a sheet where all expenses occurred go (SHEET EXPENSES). The STORE and EXPENSE DESCRIPTION provide long text describing the location and nature of each transaction. A user would have to Manually assign each entry with an EXPENSE TYPE (which has data validation on it, as confined by sheet LABELS). This is time consuming and cumbersome. I curated a list of 'search terms' (Column A) in Sheet EXPENSE TYPES that will render an Expense Type (Column B). I want Sheet Expenses Column Expense Type populated with the expense type if one or both of the description columns contain a search term.
Optional (but would be nice): If multiple search terms come back, then leave blank

Base Logic
IF [Expense Description] OR [STORE] CONTAINS *[SEARCH TERM]*, RETURN [POPULATE TYPE]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13aqcP6S0rPxkqRLfSNPaxml_yoq6ta_yjbpKZ6yFSQo/edit#gid=1927530784

It Seems like some wild combination of VLOOKUP & SEARCH would do it but I'm not finding anything that works...
This would be so easy with an alteryx or Data processing step in between but I want this google sheet to be a centralized solution. Thanks in advance. Three hours trying to figure this out. I love you mystery answer person <3

Comment: Simply post some of your sample data then show expected output and then explain briefly logic to get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In the tab 'Copy of Expenses' I entered in cell E2

```
={"Expense Type"; ArrayFormula(if(len(B3:B) + len(C3:C), iferror(vlookup(regexextract(regexreplace(LOWER(B3:B10&" "&C3:C10), "("&lower(textjoin("|", 1,  'Expense Types'!A2:A))&")","_$1_°"), "_(\w+)_"), 'Expense Types'!A2:B, 2, 0)),))}
```

I also added 'Wendy' to the tab 'Expense Types'.

See if that helps ?

[image]

Comment: This is incredible - WOW thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help ! Since you are new here, you may want to check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks! I am playing around with this new calculation now. If I change anything manually, ie manually assign an expense type to a line item, it erases everything and errors, saying "array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data" .. I tried to fix this by essentially referencing = [STORE cell3] & [Description cell3] in Column A of Expense Type Tab and =[ExpenseType cell3] in column C, but then it creates a circular reference. Even when turning off circular references in the settings it still errors

Comment: That is normal behavior. If you manually enter something in the column of  the output of the formula, the formula breaks. A workaround would be to turn the arrayformula into a formula per cell (that you then can fill down). If there is a cell where you want to do a manual input, you can then remove the formula from that cell.